# Making a house warmer

Tags: insulation

Will it make my house warmer if I put plastic over my existing walls and then cover that with paneling? My house is old and I don't want to tear out the drywall that is there now.

Comment: Are the exterior walls insulated?

Comment: Do you own it or is it a rental?

Answer (score 2):

I would not use plastic when you see homes wrapped prior to the siding it looks like plastic but it is a breathable membrane. Having the walls filled with blown in insulation would be much healthier for both the people in the home and for the structure itself.

Answer (score 1):

No. The plastic will do little, as it would insulate poorly and you likely don't have air leakage through the drywall. The paneling will offer virtually no insulation either.

You'll need to add proper insulation either in the walls (by blowing it through small holes) or installing it under the siding as foam sheets. Another thing that helps is applying film over leaky windows.

The bottom line is that there isn't enough information in your post about your home for anyone to provide a clear solution. You need to assess the critical heat loss areas and deal with them using established techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perhaps, but moisture will now be trapped and can cause mold and mildew within the wall. The plastic will act as a vapor barrier.

Comment: to expand, the cold wall can condense "dew" and collect moisture to the point of mildew.